# Calculating Last Field Name Selected

Tags: powerbi, dax

I work for a non-profit and we have a system that records the following fields for each action taken during the online donation process:

- **Date/time** (in epoch unix timestamp format)
- **Action name** (can range from clicking "next" buttons to selecting funds)
- **Session ID**

I basically want to record the last fund selected in the process (preferably as a calculated column). I currently have another column that states the type of giving form used, so I would like to drill that down into the specific funds.

Below is my desired results:
[image]

Any help would be appreciate - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=
VAR maxtimestamp =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table1[Date/Time] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Table1 ), Table1[Session ID] = EARLIER ( Table1[Session ID] ) )
    )
VAR maxfundsession =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table1[Date/Time] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Table1 ),
            LEFT ( Table1[Action], 11 ) = "Select Fund"
                && Table1[Session ID] = EARLIER ( Table1[Session ID] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        Table1[Date/Time] = maxtimestamp,
        CALCULATE (
            LASTNONBLANK ( Table1[Action], 1 ),
            FILTER (
                Table1,
                Table1[Session ID] = EARLIER ( Table1[Session ID] )
                    && Table1[Date/Time] = maxfundsession
            )
        ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

Comment: This worked! I've been working on this for what seemed like forever - THANK YOU